# How to do inference on a test dataset too large for RAM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pickle

I'm training a network to classify audio. First I extract logmel-spectrograms from my audio data, save these in arrays and train my network using these. At each epoch I inference on my test data to get an accuracy estimate.

My training dataset is 24GB and test dataset is 6GB. Both are too large for the RAM. I found that I could extract the logmel-specs from my training data before running the network, save each minibatch in a pickle file, then load these one by one during training.

However, I use `.eval()` to get the accuracy from my my whole test data at once. This worked when I used smaller datasets as there was no need to split my data up into chunks using different pickle files. However, I'm now trying to figure out how to run the `.eval()` line or equivalent so that it provides accuracy for the whole test dataset, rather than the smaller chunks I've split it into. Is there a way I can get overall accuracy for my test data using pickle files or another method?

Here is the key component of code at the end where I think this can be done:

```
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels_input, 1)) 
test_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float')) #changes correct to type: float
test_accuracy1 = test_accuracy.eval({features_input:X_test, labels_input:y_test}) 
test_accuracy_scores.append(test_accuracy1)
print('Test accuracy:', test_accuracy1)
```

Here is my entire codeblock for the network:

```
### Train NN, output results
r"""This uses the VGGish model definition within a larger model which adds two 
layers on top, and then trains this larger model. 

We input log-mel spectrograms (X_train) calculated above with associated labels 
(y_train), and feed the batches into the model. Once the model is trained, it 
is then executed on the test log-mel spectrograms (X_test) and the accuracy is output.

Alongside .csv file with the predictions for each 0.96s chunk and their true
class is also output for the test data. Column1 = the logit for the first class,
Column2 = the logit for the scond class etc. The final column is the true class.
"""

num_min_batches = len(os.listdir(pickle_files_dir))/2
os.chdir(scripts_directory)  

def main(X):   
  with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Define VGGish.
    embeddings = vggish_slim.define_vggish_slim(training=FLAGS.train_vggish)
    
    
    # Define a shallow classification model and associated training ops on top
    # of VGGish.
    with tf.variable_scope('mymodel'):
      # Add a fully connected layer with 100 units. Add an activation function
      # to the embeddings since they are pre-activation.
      num_units = 100
      fc = slim.fully_connected(tf.nn.relu(embeddings), num_units)

      # Add a classifier layer at the end, consisting of parallel logistic
      # classifiers, one per class. This allows for multi-class tasks.
      logits = slim.fully_connected(         
          fc, _NUM_CLASSES, activation_fn=None, scope='logits')
      tf.sigmoid(logits, name='prediction')
    
      linear_out= slim.fully_connected(                                      
          fc, _NUM_CLASSES, activation_fn=None, scope='linear_out')
      logits = tf.sigmoid(linear_out, name='logits')
    
      # Add training ops.
      with tf.variable_scope('train'):
        global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()

        # Labels are assumed to be fed as a batch multi-hot vectors, with
        # a 1 in the position of each positive class label, and 0 elsewhere.
        labels_input = tf.placeholder(
            tf.float32, shape=(None, _NUM_CLASSES), name='labels')

        # Cross-entropy label loss.
        xent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=logits, labels=labels_input, name='xent')    
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(xent, name='loss_op')
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

        # We use the same optimizer and hyperparameters as used to train VGGish.
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
            learning_rate=vggish_params.LEARNING_RATE,
            epsilon=vggish_params.ADAM_EPSILON)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

    # Initialize all variables in the model, and then load the pre-trained
    # VGGish checkpoint.
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())        
    vggish_slim.load_vggish_slim_checkpoint(sess, FLAGS.checkpoint)

    # The training loop.
    features_input = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(
        vggish_params.INPUT_TENSOR_NAME)   

    validation_accuracy_scores = []
    test_accuracy_scores = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i=0
            while i < num_min_batches: 
                #print('mini batch'+str(i))
                X_pickle_file = pickle_files_dir + 'X_train_mini_batch_' + str(i)
                with open(X_pickle_file, "rb") as fp:   # Unpickling
                  batch_x = pickle.load(fp)
                
                y_pickle_file = pickle_files_dir + 'y_train_mini_batch_' + str(i)
                with open(y_pickle_file, "rb") as fp:   # Unpickling
                  batch_y = pickle.load(fp)

                _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={features_input: batch_x, labels_input: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+=1
            #print no. of epochs and loss
            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of', num_epochs,', loss:',epoch_loss) 

            #note this adds a small computational cost
            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels_input, 1)) 
            test_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float')) #changes correct to type: float
            test_accuracy1 = test_accuracy.eval({features_input:X_test, labels_input:y_test}) 
            test_accuracy_scores.append(test_accuracy1)
            print('Test accuracy:', test_accuracy1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Comment: Your test accuracy is just the mean of correct prediction on your batch, so if you take the mean of the test_accuracy1 on all batch of test_data you would just have your test accuracy or do I miss smthg ?

Comment: Doing some scribbles on paper with a calculator I think you're right, seems too good to be true!